# AEM 6.0 on docker - Dbus connection error

Tags: docker, centos, aem, centos7, devops

I'm trying to dockerize an AEM 6.0 installation, and this is the Dockerfile for my author.

```
from centos:latest

COPY aem6.0-author-p4502.jar /AEM/aem/author/aem6.0-author-p4502.jar
COPY license.properties /AEM/aem/author/license.properties

RUN yum install dnsmasq -y
RUN systemctl enable dnsmasq
RUN yum install initscripts -y
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

WORKDIR /AEM/aem/author
RUN yum install wget -y
RUN wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.rpm"
RUN yum localinstall jdk-8u151-linux-x64.rpm -y
RUN java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx512M -jar aem6.0-author-p4502.jar -unpack

COPY aem6 /etc/init.d/aem6
RUN chkconfig --add aem6
RUN yum -y install initscripts && yum update -y & yum clean all

RUN chown -R $USER:$(id -G) /etc/init.d
RUN chmod 777 -R /etc/init.d/aem6
RUN systemctl enable aem6.service 
RUN service aem6 start
VOLUME /sys/fs/cgroup
CMD /usr/sbin/init
```

The build fails on starting the service, with the error - `failed to get Dbus connection error`. I haven't been able to figure out how to fix it.

I've tried these
 - https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/issues/45
 - https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/

Comment: Docker images don't run systemd, so this won't work. You need to run supervisord to launch multiple processes or services.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with docker. But I would be nice if information like 1) Docker Version 2) CentOS Version are also provided.

Comment: Docker images *can* run systemd, but that's not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the problem is that you're trying to start the `aem` service during the "build" phase, with this statement:

```
RUN service aem6 start
```

This is problematic for a number of reasons.  First, you're building an image.  Starting a service at this stage is pointless...when the build process completes, *nothing* is running.  An image is just a collection of files. You don't have any *processes* until you boot a container, at which point your `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` influence what is running.

Another problem is that at this stage, nothing else is running inside the container environment.  The `service` command in this case is trying to communicate with `systemd` using the `dbus` api, but neither of those services are running.

There is a third slightly more subtle problem: the solution you've chosen relies on `systemd`, the standard CentOS process manager, and as far as things go you've configured things correctly (by both enabling the service with `systemctl enable ...` and by starting `/sbin/init` in your `CMD` statement).  However, running systemd in a container can be tricky, although it is possible.  In the past, `systemd` required the container to run with the `--privileged` flag; I'm not sure if this is necessary any more.

If you weren't running multiple processes (dnsmasq and aem) inside the container, the simplest solution would be to start the `aem` service directly, rather than relying on a process manager.  This would reduce your Dockerfile to something like:

```
FROM centos:latest

COPY aem6.0-author-p4502.jar /AEM/aem/author/aem6.0-author-p4502.jar
COPY license.properties /AEM/aem/author/license.properties

WORKDIR /AEM/aem/author
RUN yum install wget -y
RUN wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.rpm"
RUN yum localinstall jdk-8u151-linux-x64.rpm -y
RUN java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx512M -jar aem6.0-author-p4502.jar -unpack

CMD some commandline to start aem
```

If you actually require dnsmasq, you could run it in a second container (potentially sharing the same network environment as the aem container).

Comment: Incidentally, I would rewrite `FROM centos:latest` as `FROM centos:7`, otherwise you're setting yourself up for trouble in the future if CentOS 8 comes out and it isn't compatible with your software.